# unable to display csv file and take file input for ggplot in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new in shiny I am trying to make an app using shiny and shinydasboard. I shiny, I have created an action button which I am using for uploading CSV files and after this i am making ggplot based on this file.

Problems:

1. I want to display csv file in my app instead of R console .
2. I can't find how to take final csv file after performing operations as an input for plot.

Sample of my dataset:

```
      A        B     Class
    50.00    90.00     A
    50.01    91.00     A
    50.05    91.05     B
    51.50    91.09     C
    51.09    90.20     D
```

ui.R

```
ui <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(menuItem("choose",tabName = "choose")),
  menuItem("Plot",tabName = "Plot")
  body <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "choose",
          fluidRow(
          actionButton("select", "select"),
 ) 
 tabItem(tabName = "plot",
          fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot"))))
 )
```

server.R

```
select <- function(){
dataframe <- read.table(file.choose(),header = TRUE, sep = "," 
,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
attach(dataframe)

dataframe1 <- subset(dataframe, select = c(A,B))
dataframe2 <- dataframe %>% mutate(variance1 = var(A)) %>% 
mutate(variance2 = var(B))
return(print(dataframe2))
}

server <- function(input,output){
 observeEvent(
 input$select,{
  select()
 }
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
  pd <- input$dataframe2
  pd1 <- ggplot(pd, aes(y = A, x = B, colour = Class)) +geom_point() + 
print(pd1)
})
 shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Put this 2 widgets together: [file upload](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) and [display table](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html)

Comment: @zx8754 I tried this but it's not working because I have to perform operations on CSV file. I have to add 2 rows then I have to display the CSV file and take this file as an input in plots.

Comment: @zx8754 Can you help me out in this problem?